# Trouble filtering by multiple conditions from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, filter, react-redux

Filtering with multiple options in React Redux:

filterOption:

```
{
    option1: ['GY'],
    option2: ['Y'],
    option3: [],
    option4: ['N'],
    option5: ['A', 'W'],
}
```

The filter function:

```
body.search.listFiltered = body.search.list.filter(
    (i) =>
        filterOption["option1"].includes(i.s) &&
        filterOption["option2"].includes(i.b) &&
        filterOption["option3"].includes(i.u.p) &&
        filterOption["option4"].includes(i.f.p) &&
        filterOption["option5"].includes(i.n.p)
);
```

It should work even when for example `option3` is empty—it could be any other option for that matter.

Each `option-x` works with a particular object, such as `option1` with object `i.s`. While `option2` with `i.b` and so forth...

Right now it's returning an empty array `[]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are u getting any error?

Comment: Nothing, it just returns an empty array. When I have 1 or 2 options only it works (but their array need to be with values). But with multiple like above it just doesn't. @NeelDsouza

Comment: If you trying to check Array.includes when your Array is empty it's allways will return false, so if you have an empty array in your filterOption, you will be always return the empty filtered array

Comment: You can first check for empty arrays in filterOption, then filter body

Comment: @Yaroslav But sometimes some of the `option-X` arrays will be empty. How do I fix the filter then?

Comment: @Yaroslav Is there any way I can exclude the empty ones inside `filter()`? Cause it would be too messy otherwise. How would I even go about creating dynamic conditions inside `filter()`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```js
const filterOption = {
option1: ['GY'],
option2: [true],
option3: [],
option4: [false],
option5: ['A', 'W']
 }
 
const array = [{b:'GY'},{s:true},{p:'A'},{x:false},{e:'A'}, {b:'GY',s:true,p:'A', x:false, e:'A'  }]

 
const result = array.filter(
(i) =>
{
const filterCheck = option => item => filterOption[option].length > 0 ?   filterOption[option].includes(item) : true

return  filterCheck("option1")(i.b) &&
    
        filterCheck("option2")(i.s) &&
    
        filterCheck("option3")(i.p) &&
    
        filterCheck("option4")(i.x) &&
    
        filterCheck("option5")(i.e)}
    
)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: The thing is, I have `filterOption['option1']` etc... because they all match up to a specific object in `includes()`.

Comment: For example `option1` goes with object `i.s`. While `option2` with `i.b` and so forth...

Comment: So it's not possible to do it this way. Especially because some of the options are booleans.

Comment: updated, maybe that will work? the only thing is decide what you want to do when the filterOption array is Empty

Comment: It cannot be `true` because `option` `3-5` have boolean values only. So if `false` is selected for either of them, both true and false will be shown...

Comment: I tried adding a string `["hello"]`  to all variables. But still doesn't work.